# Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv:

Tags: jquery, html, csv

I generate a csv file in the server side and make it available in the client side. I get this message in Google Chromes Developer Tools Console when I attempt to download a csv file : `Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type text/csv` and an pop up that says "error"

This is the tag I'm using to let the client download the file

```
    <a type="text/csv" href="download.csv">download</a>
```

How do I transfer the file without receiving that message in the console?

Comment: ensure the server is returning the file with the correct mimetype?

Comment: @KevinB it looks like the content type in the response headers is "text/csv", but the status says "(canceled)"

Comment: the warning you are seeing is saying that the browser expected to see "Document" but instead received text/csv

Comment: The file was correctly transfered with the text/csv mimetype, but the browser interpreted it as a Document. i don't think this has anything to do with javascript html or jquery, as you're essentially navigating directly to the csv.

Comment: Okay, but this kills all of the other network requests(ajax calls). What do you suggest as a work-around?

Comment: you could do `target="_blank"` or make it target a hidden iframe

Comment: This is a server issue similar to the font issues that are common.  It's not critical and the download should still work, but to get it to not throw the message you need to edit your server config file (e.g. .htaccess, php.ini, or whatever the other server types use).

Comment: @KevinB, I've made it target="_blank" and this is the solution I've used. If you want to answer the question, feel free and I will marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making your anchor tag target another page should cause the warning to show up on the new page rather than the current page, but since the new page will be immediately closed, it won't be noticeable.

```
target="_blank"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) attribute, but it it has [limited browser support right now](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download).

You could probably [combine this](https://output.jsbin.com/jesurutusu/1) with a `target="_blank"` with no ill effects.